# Why is my React Native class component returning the error: this.setState is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's the code for my class component:

```
export class RenderButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isCollapsed: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    var buttonText = this.state.isCollapsed === true ? "Expand" : "Collapse";

    // helper components
    function _renderSquareButton({ item }) {
      return (
        <SquareButton
          name={item.name}
          onPress={() => this.props.pressHandler()}
        />
      );
    }

    function _header(name) {
      return (
        <View style={views.nameAndPriceContainer}>
          <Text style={text.headerTwo}>{name}</Text>
          <Button title={buttonText} onPress={() => toggleCollapsed()} />
        </View>
      );
    }

    function toggleCollapsed() {
      this.setState((currentState) => {
        return { isCollapsed: !currentState.isCollapsed };
      });
    }

    return (
      <FlatList
        listKey={this.props.name}
        ListHeaderComponent={_header(this.props.name)}
        data={this.props.data}
        extraData={this.props.data}
        renderItem={_renderSquareButton}
        numColumns={4}
        refreshing={true}
        extraData={this.props.data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name + index}
        ListEmptyComponent={null}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to press the expand/collapse button and says "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({ ... })" so I assume it's with the toggleCollapsed function.

Edit, thanks everyone the problem has been solved. Here's the working code for anyone interested:

```
export class RenderButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            isCollapsed:false,
        }
        this._renderSquareButton = this._renderSquareButton.bind(this); 
        this._header = this._header.bind(this);
        this.toggleCollapsed= this.toggleCollapsed.bind(this);
    }

    // helper components
    _renderSquareButton({ item }){
        return <SquareButton name={item.name} onPress={()=>this.props.pressHandler()} />
    }

    _header( name ){
       var buttonText = this.state.isCollapsed === true ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse';
        return(
            <View style={ views.nameAndPriceContainer }>
                <Text style={ text.headerTwo }>{ name }</Text>
                <Button title= { buttonText } onPress={()=> this.toggleCollapsed() } />
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    toggleCollapsed(){
        this.setState( currentState => {
            return { isCollapsed: !currentState.isCollapsed };
        });
    }


    render(){
        switch( this.state.isCollapsed ){
            case false:
                return (
                    <FlatList
                        listKey={ this.props.name }
                        ListHeaderComponent={this._header( this.props.name )}
                        data={ this.props.data } extraData={ this.props.data }
                        renderItem={ this._renderSquareButton }
                        numColumns={ 4 }
                        refreshing={ true }
                        extraData={ this.props.data }
                        keyExtractor={( item, index )=> item.name + index }
                        ListEmptyComponent={ null }
                    />
                )
            break;
            case true:
                return this._header( this.props.name )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to bind the method to make `this` work properly. Please go through the docs for detailed explanation and examples (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: setState(!state) will make the state reverse.

you don't need to do setState(()=>(!state))

state is he'd in a separate async chain thing, so do functions and then change the state at the end, do not do functions in the satState function even if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just necessary to bind function `toggleCollapsed` in `constructor` like this:

```
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            isCollapsed:false,
        }
     this.toggleCollapsed = this.toggleCollapsed.bind(this);
    }
```

This should solve your problem.

Anyway I would suggest you to refactor your code in this way:

```
export class RenderButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            isCollapsed:false,
        }
        this._renderSquareButton = this._renderSquareButton.bind(this); 
        this._header = this._header.bind(this);
        this.toggleCollapsed= this.toggleCollapsed.bind(this);
    }

    // helper components
    _renderSquareButton({ item }){
        return <SquareButton name={item.name} onPress={()=>this.props.pressHandler()} />
    }

    _header( name ){
       var buttonText = this.state.isCollapsed === true ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse';
        return(
            <View style={ views.nameAndPriceContainer }>
                <Text style={ text.headerTwo }>{ name }</Text>
                <Button title= { buttonText } onPress={()=> this.toggleCollapsed() } />
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    toggleCollapsed(){
        this.setState( currentState => {
            return { isCollapsed: !currentState.isCollapsed };
        });
    }


    render(){
    return (
        <FlatList
            listKey={ this.props.name }
            ListHeaderComponent={this._header( this.props.name )}
            data={ this.props.data } extraData={ this.props.data }
            renderItem={ this._renderSquareButton }
            numColumns={ 4 }
            refreshing={ true }
            extraData={ this.props.data }
            keyExtractor={( item, index )=> item.name + index }
            ListEmptyComponent={ null }
        />
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, now I get 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.toggleCollapsed')

Answer (score 1):

Change your **ToggleCollapsed** into following

```js
function toggleCollapsed(){
  this.setState({
    isCollapsed: !this.state.isCollapsed;
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update a few things:

- Move `toggleCollapsed` to outside `render`.
- Update `onPress={this.toggleCollapsed}`
- Add `this.toggleCollapsed = this.toggleCollapsed.bind(this)` in `constructor`, after `this.state`

Comment: Tried this, now I get 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.toggleCollapsed')

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(false);
```

Maybe this can help you

also no need to compare a bool to === true.

```
let buttonText = this.state.isCollapsed ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse';
```